# How to use Collections.sort() in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, spring-mvc, collections

I got an object `Recipe` that implements `Comparable<Recipe>` :

```
public int compareTo(Recipe otherRecipe) {
    return this.inputRecipeName.compareTo(otherRecipe.inputRecipeName);
}
```

I've done that so I'm able to sort the `List` alphabetically in the following method:

```
public static Collection<Recipe> getRecipes(){
    List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>(RECIPE_MAP.values());
    Collections.sort(recipes);
    return recipes;
}
```

But now, in a different method, lets call it `getRecipesSort()`, I want to sort the same list but numerically, comparing a variable that contains their ID. To make things worse, the ID field is of the type `String`.

How do I use Collections.sort() to perform the sorts in Java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: @BrianRoach I'm sorry if I don't meet your requirements for answering. I know where the documentation is, I'm just looking for creative solutions, since I can't seem to find any. Down-voting was just purely ridiculous but oh well, frustration can't be explained.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use this method [Collections.sort(List,Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) . Implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass it to `Collections.sort().`

```
class RecipeCompare implements Comparator<Recipe> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Recipe o1, Recipe o2) {
        // write comparison logic here like below , it's just a sample
        return o1.getID().compareTo(o2.getID());
    }
}
```

Then use the `Comparator` as

```
Collections.sort(recipes,new RecipeCompare());
```

Comment: Almost. The OP wants to compare based on the ID fields, which are Strings, but to compare them numerically. We don't know the range, but if they fit in ints then converting to int and comparing would work, otherwise an appropriate type would have to be chosen or a more complicated comparator written, but this is the right approach.

Comment: Actually, I kind of like the simplicity of this answer, it made me think how I'd do it, I'm working on it now.

Answer (score 29):

The answer given by *NINCOMPOOP* can be made simpler using Lambda Expressions:

`Collections.sort(recipes, (Recipe r1, Recipe r2) ->`
`r1.getID().compareTo(r2.getID()));`

Also introduced after Java 8 is the comparator construction methods in the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface. Using these, one can further reduce this to <sup>1</sup>:

```
recipes.sort(comparingInt(Recipe::getId));
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Bloch, J. *Effective Java* (3<sup>rd</sup> Edition). 2018. Item 42, p. 194.

Answer (score 7):

Create a comparator which accepts the compare mode in its constructor and pass different modes for different scenarios based on your requirement

```
public class RecipeComparator implements Comparator<Recipe> {

public static final int COMPARE_BY_ID = 0;
public static final int COMPARE_BY_NAME = 1;

private int compare_mode = COMPARE_BY_NAME;

public RecipeComparator() {
}

public RecipeComparator(int compare_mode) {
    this.compare_mode = compare_mode;
}

@Override
public int compare(Recipe o1, Recipe o2) {
    switch (compare_mode) {
    case COMPARE_BY_ID:
        return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
    default:
        return o1.getInputRecipeName().compareTo(o2.getInputRecipeName());
    }
}
```

}

Actually for numbers you need to handle them separately check below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string1 = "1";
    String string2 = "2";
    String string11 = "11";

    System.out.println(string1.compareTo(string2)); 
    System.out.println(string2.compareTo(string11));// expected -1 returns 1
   // to compare numbers you actually need to do something like this

    int number2 = Integer.valueOf(string1);
    int number11 = Integer.valueOf(string11);

    int compareTo = number2 > number11 ? 1 : (number2 < number11 ? -1 : 0) ;
    System.out.println(compareTo);// prints -1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the method that accepts a `Comparator` when you want to sort in something other than natural order.

[Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 0):

Sort the unsorted hashmap in ascending order.

```
// Sorting the list based on values
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) 
{
                return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });

    // Maintaining insertion order with the help of LinkedList
    Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```