# Java Collections Comparator incompatable types error? Why Doesn't my Comparator return anything?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I based my code on this:
[How to use Collections.sort() in Java ? (Specific situation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425127/how-to-use-collections-sort-in-java-specific-situation)

I have a bunch of view models in two ArrayLists. Which I intend to merge together and sort. I know I could write my own merge sort but I wanted to try using Java's built in sort.

Right now I have something like this:

```
public class ViewModelBuilder {
    public List<ViewModel> mergeViewModelLists(List<ViewModel> a, List<ViewModel> b) {
        List<ViewModel> mergedList = a.addAll(b); //where all lists are ArrayLists
        List<ViewModel> sortedList = Collections.sort(mergedList, new ViewModelDateComparator());
        return sortedList;
    }
}

class ViewModelDateComparator implements Comparator<ViewModel> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ViewModel m1, ViewModel m2) {
        //requestDate returns a java.utils.date
        return m1.requestDate().compareTo(m2.requestDate());
    }
}
```

I read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,java.util.Comparator%29

And I thought that this was correct? However my code doesn't compile. On hover over the error on my Collections.sort line is

> "Incompatable types, required Java.util.list<ViewModel> Found void."

Is there a method that I'm missing? (also sorry I typed the code above so if theres a typo my apologies. Everything in my editor compiles except for that one line)

Comment: Look at the docs for `Collections.sort`. What does it do? What does it return?

Comment: You are using the variable "cleanedList" but you haven't defined it anywhere

Comment: @mystery downvoter, why the downvote? It was an honest misunderstanding.

Comment: _incompatible_ or _incomparable_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Collections.sort` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) sorts the `List` in place; it returns `void`, and you can't assign the result of a `void`-returning method to anything.

Call `Collections.sort` without assigning the result to anything, and return `cleanedList`.

It may be a typo in your question, but `cleanedList` isn't defined in the code you supply, and you don't do anything with `mergedList`.  It's possible that you intended to sort `mergedList` instead, unless you left out code that converts `mergedList` to `cleanedList`.  Pass the appropriate `List` to `Collections.sort` and return it.

<sub>*Update*: The question has now been edited so that `mergedList` is the `List` being sorted, not `cleanedList`.</sub>

Comment: Oh Awesome! I misunderstood clearly :) thank you. I'll accepted (I have to wait 10 minutes)

Comment: If it resolved your problem , then consider accepting answer by clicking check mark, it will get you both some reputation. And in future people will know this solution works

Comment: @Panther I was waiting for the 10 minute expiration, and then I got distracted doing something else sorry