# How do show specific recyclerview items at the top?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview, adapter

Let's say I have web-request for a list of meals and implemented using a Recyclerview, now what if I want to sort/move specific items at the top..!

---

**Meal:** *Italian Pasta* **| Type:** *pasta* **| Price:** 20$

**Meal:** *Hotdogs Pizza* **| Type:** *pizza* **| Price:** 10$

**Meal:** *Burger*        **| Type:** *fast food* **| Price:** 30$

**Meal:** *Rice*          **| Type:** *lunch* **| Price:** 18$

**Meal:** *Mac & Cheese*  **| Type:** *lunch* **| Price:** 17$

**Meal:** *CheeseBurger*  **| Type:** *fast food* **| Price:** 8$

---

So for example, what I want is for every item who has a type of `fast food` and `pizza` to show at the top of the list and then the rest..!?

where do I perform this sorting logic, is it inside the adapter or the activity of the recyclerview? is there like an existing method for this function like `moveToTop()` to be used like this:

```
for(Meals item: dataList){

   if (item.getType.equals("fast food") || item.getType.equals("pizza")){
      item.moveToTop(); 
   }

}
```

Is it possible?

---

### Update 2

I figured out, I found a method a special parameter of interface for the recyclerview in these situations `SortedListAdapterCallback`

```
if (homeData.size() > 0) {

            Collections.sort(homeData, Collections.reverseOrder(new SortedListAdapterCallback<HomeItemModel>(adapter) {
              @Override
              public int compare(HomeItemModel o1, HomeItemModel o2) {

               int weight1;
               int weight2;

               if(item1.getType.equals("fast food") || item1.getType.equals("pizza")){
                   weight1 = 1;
               }else{
                   weight1 = 0;
               }

               if(item2.getType.equals("fast food") || item2.getType.equals("pizza")){
                weight2 = 1;
               }else{
                weight2 = 0;
               }

                if (weight1 == weight2)
                   return 0;
                else if (weight1 > weight2)
                   return 1;
                else
                   return -1;

                 }

              @Override
              public boolean areContentsTheSame(HomeItemModel oldItem, HomeItemModel newItem) {
                return false;
              }

              @Override
              public boolean areItemsTheSame(HomeItemModel item1, HomeItemModel item2) {
                return false;
              }
            }));

          }
```

The only problem here, is the order at the top..! they show like this:

- fast food
- pizza
- pizza
- fast food
- pizza
- fast food
- ... the rest of the list

**I want them to show ordered.. like this:**

- fast food // or the pizzas first
- fast food
- fast food
- pizza
- pizza
- pizza
- ... the rest of the list

Can this be done..?

Comment: You have to sort your list. How you decide to do that is up to you

Comment: Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054262/best-way-to-sort-a-list-using-two-different-fields
Though it is not android specific but it may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Comparator inside your POJO class Meals

```
public static class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Meals> {
    public int compare(Meals  item1, Meals  item2) {

        int weight1;
        int weight2;

        if(item1.getType.equals("fast food") || item1.getType.equals("pizza")){
            weight1 = 1;
        }else{
            weight1 = 0;
        }

        if(item2.getType.equals("fast food") || item2.getType.equals("pizza")){
            weight2 = 1;
        }else{
            weight2 = 0;
        }


        if (weight1 == weight2)
            return 0;
        else if (weight1 > weight2)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

And before setting your adapter call this line then pass the data list into your Adapter constructor.

```
Collections.sort(yourDataLIst, Collections.reverseOrder(new Meals.CustomComparator()));
```

**EDIT**
If you want to all fast food first then pizza and then all the list 
then just tweak your sort logic as below

```
        if(item1.getType.equals("fast food")){
            weight1 = 2;
        }else if (item1.getType.equals("pizza")){
            weight1 = 1;
        } else {
            weight1 = 0;
        }

        if(item2.getType.equals("fast food")){
            weight2 = 2;
        }else if (item2.getType.equals("pizza")){
            weight2 = 1;
        } else{
            weight2 = 0;
        }
```

Comment: not working, the list wasn't ordered? are you sure about this logic?

Comment: List doesn't have to be ordered. `sort` function will sort them according to your Comparator logic. And you can check the logic by yourself whether you want something like this or not?

Comment: I solved it, approve the edit.. could you help with the slight problem with the solution..!

Comment: Post last part in your question

Comment: I'm having a problem, in the example.. the types of meals are set manually, but in my real code they are not. First, it's hobbies not meal types and the user can select from a list of them once the app gets launched and in the next screen the selected hobbies will show at the top from data list, then the rest..! I tried a few soulton but they didn't work, the one in this gist here, it only show the first item in the hobbies arraylist and ignores the other selected.!? please help me with this.. https://gist.github.com/AlaaZarifa/f03400c35f32288eb9f5b25391aed2de

Comment: How are you ensuring which will go on top? You must be storing somewhere those values.

Comment: I'm not, but It's okay I solved after a lot of tries..! I removed the `for-each` and replaced the other condition with "contains" and it worked :D check the gist. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple method like `moveToTop()` in **Arraylist**. But you can shift the data manually.

You can do that like this:

```
for(Meals item: dataList){

   if (item.getType.equals("fast food") || item.getType.equals("pizza")){
      int index = dataList.indexOf(item);
      dataList.remove(index);
      dataList.add(0, item);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   }

}
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: didn't work, I put it inside the activity after setting the recyclerview to the adapter~! should it be elsewhere !?

Comment: to update UI you have to call 'notifyDataSetChanged()'. See my answer. If it is not resolved your issue post your activity code.

Comment: it only showed the one item at the top, not all of them..? something missing in the for loop maybe? see the Update for the code..!