# Java: ArrayList<String> sorting using comparators (ArrayLists doesn't store objects)

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I want to sort an ArrayList of type String using a comparator. I have only found examples on how to do it if an ArrayList stores objects.

I have an ArrayList of strings that have 10 symbols and last 5 of those symbols are digits that form a number. I want to solve an array list in ascending order of those numbers that are at the end of each string. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: `String` **is** an `Object`. What have you tried (exactly)? Let's see some code.

Comment: `private static ArrayList<String> allCodes = new ArrayList<String>();   //add some codes in ....
 private void sortAllCodesNumbers (){
        Collections.sort(allCodes, allCodes.getCompByNum());
    } `

Comment: `public static Comparator<String> getCompByNum()
{
 Comparator comp = new Comparator<String>(){
     @Override
     public int compare(allBooks b1, allBooks b2)
     {
         String IDnumbers1 = b1.substring(AUTHOR_ID_LENGHT+GENRE_LENGTH);
         int number1 = Integer.parseInt(IDnumbers1);

         String IDnumbers2 = b2.substring(AUTHOR_ID_LENGHT+GENRE_LENGTH);
         int number2 = Integer.parseInt(IDnumbers1);

         return number1.compareTo(number2);
     }
 };
 return comp;
}`

Comment: Variant of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425127/how-to-use-collections-sort-in-java-specific-situation ?

Comment: check this:List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("abc456");
  list.add("abc123");
  list.add("abc012");
  System.out.println(list);
  Collections.sort(list);
  System.out.println(list); output:[abc456, abc123, abc012]
[abc012, abc123, abc456]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to accomplish your task; `sorted` accepts a `Comparator` object.

```
List<String> result = myArrayList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.substring(5))))
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or simply:

```
myArrayList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.substring(5))));
```

Comment: No need for a regexp. Why not just e.substring(5)?

Comment: @JBNizet true, I shall use your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Collections.sort can sort you a list with a Comparator. Plus you need String.substring:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.substring(5).compareTo(o2.substring(5));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(list, String::compareTo);
```

The above code does the job.

If you want more control, you could use/chain with one of the static methods available in the Comparator Interface.

```
Collectios.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(String::CompareTo).thenComparingInt(String::length));
```