# Sort Java list of objects

Tags: java, list, sorting, object

I need to sort a java list containing objects of type **Hotel**

```
List<Hotel> hotelList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside the class I do have the method

```
    @Override
public List<Room> getAvailableRooms() {

    return this.rooms;
}
```

I need to sort my hotelList by the `price` attribute found in **Room** class.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Which price?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Collections.sort() in Java ? (Specific situation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425127/how-to-use-collections-sort-in-java-specific-situation)

Comment: price is an attribute of Room class

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a Comparator or implement the Comparable interface

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<ToSort> {

private int val;

public Foo(int val){
    this.val = val;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ToSort f) {

    if (val > f.val) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (val <  f.val) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Read more here
https://dzone.com/articles/sorting-java-arraylist